# how can update my form in modal in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

hello i am creating mean application in which i want to update record.the record is in table format and when user click on edit button then a modal appears with its database values on input text box . I have not any problem in updating field but i stuck in updating video part. How can I do it??
html form (i use single form for creating and updating)

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Add Videos</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div style="margin:10px;">
      <form name="addVideos" class="" method="post">
        <div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="success" style="background-color:black;">
          <strong>successfully updated!!</strong> Redirecting to all videos page.
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="form.title" required name="title" placeholder="Enter Title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Description</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="form.description" required name="description" rows="5" id="comment" placeholder="Enter Description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Author</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="form.author" name="author" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Enter Author Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>duration</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="form.duration" name="duration" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Enter Author Name">
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="form-group">
          <label>ispublic</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="form.public" name="public" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Enter Author Name">
        </div> -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="sel1">ispublic:</label>
          <select class="form-control"  ng-model="form.public" >
            <option  ng-selected="test==false" value="0">0</option>
            <option  ng-selected="test==true" value="1">1</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top: 19px;" >
            <!-- <!ng-hide="display" !> -->
            <input type="file" accept="video/*" file-model="myFile" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-left:29px;">
            <button ng-click="add == true ? uploadFile(form) : updateVideo()" class="btn btn-danger" ng-disabled="addVideos.$invalid" style="margin:10px;">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <progress value="{{progressBar}}" max="100" ng-show="view">
        </progress>
        <div class="progress" ng-show="view" style="width:40%;">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{progressBar}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{progressBar}}%">
            {{progressBar}}% Complete (success)
          </div>
        </div>


      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my controller

```
function generateUUID() {
  var d = new Date().getTime();
  var uuid = 'xxxxxxx.mp4'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
    d = Math.floor(d / 16);
    return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
  });
  return uuid;
};
var localstorageApp =  angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.videos.allVideos');
  localstorageApp.controller('TbleCtrl',['$rootScope','$scope', '$filter', 'editableOptions', 'editableThemes', '$window', '$http',
   '$uibModal', 'baProgressModal','localStorageService','$state','$rootScope',

  function ($rootScope,$scope, $filter, editableOptions, editableThemes, $window, $http, $uibModal,
    baProgressModal,localStorageService,$state,$rootScope) {

    var token = localStorageService.get('TOKEN')
    if(token == null){
      $window.location.href = '/index.html';
    }
    token = token.substring(1, token.length - 1);
    $http.get("/api/loggedin/"+token).then(function(response) {
    console.log("response"+JSON.stringify(response.data.error))
    if(response.data.error == true){
      localStorageService.remove('TOKEN')
      $window.location.href = '/index.html';
    }
    });
    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.display=true;
    // $scope.form = [];
    //$scope.bool = null;
    $scope.id = 0;
    $scope.redirect = function () {
        $window.location.href = "#/videos/addVideos";
    }
    $http.get("/api/all-videos").then(function(response) {
              $scope.users = response.data.data;
               console.log(response.data.data);
            });


    $scope.open = function(e,id,page, size, addOrEdit) {
      $scope.updateVideo() = function(){
        alert('working');
      }

      // $scope.bool = bool
      $scope.id = id
      $scope.display=true;
      var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        // animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
        // ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
        // ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
        templateUrl: page,
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        controllerAs: '$scope',
        size: size,
        // appendTo: parentElem,
        resolve: {
          users: function () {
            return $scope.users;
          },

          id: function () {
            return $scope.id;
          }
        }
      });

      modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        // console.log("selectedItem"+JSON.stringify(selectedItem.data));

          $scope.users = selectedItem;
          // $scope.users.push(selectedItem.data)

      }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
      });
    };


    $scope.removeVideo = function(id, $index) {
      var m = parseInt(id);
      if ($window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?") == true) {
        $http.post("/api/delete-video/" + m).then(function(response) {
          $scope.users.splice( $index, 1 );
        });
        // $window.location.reload()
      } else {
      }
    }


    $scope.openProgressDialog = baProgressModal.open;
    // editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
    // editableThemes['bs3'].submitTpl = '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-with-icon"><i class="ion-checkmark-round"></i></button>';
    // editableThemes['bs3'].cancelTpl = '<button type="button" ng-click="$form.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default btn-with-icon"><i class="ion-close-round"></i></button>';
  }
])
var qwe='';






angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.users').directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
      var modelSetter = model.assign;

      element.bind('change', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
          qwe= element[0].files[0];
          console.log(element[0].files[0].name);
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]).service('hexafy', ['$http', '$window','$timeout', function($http, $window,$timeout) {
  this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return x.toString(16);
    }

    // GET ALL INFORMATION IN VIDEOS
    this.getAll = function(t,x){
      console.log(x);
      $http.get("/api/get-video/"+x).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
       //  console.log(response.data.data);
       console.log(response.data.response.data);
       t.form = response.data.response.data;
       // $scope.form.public = response.data.response.data.ispublic;
      t.test = response.data.response.data.ispublic;

       // console.log($scope.form.level);
       // $scope.form.level = $scope.levels[response.data.response.data.level - 1];
       // console.log($scope.form.level);
   });
 }
 this.display = function(p){
   console.log(p);
   console.log(qwe);

 }
 this.updateVideo = function(){
   console.log(qwe);
   alert('working');
 }
 }]).controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', '$http',  'id', '$timeout','hexafy' ,function ($scope, $uibModalInstance,$http,id,$timeout,hexafy) {
  $scope.form = {};
  $scope.test = '';
  // $scope.b = bool;
  console.log($scope.b);
$scope.display=true;
console.log(hexafy.myFunc(187));
hexafy.getAll($scope,id);
console.log("id value "+id)
var file = $scope.myFile;
console.log(file);

}])
```

How could i detect file in modal??

Comment: Can you narrow the code down to the minimum needed to duplicate your issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Please consider using an app like Plunker to help duplicate your issue for others to see.